# skip the particular column for insert in entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have a default value in Database. When I was inserting a new record, that time I need to avoid the default value column in the entity.

For Example:
CreatedDate Default value in database

but in my UI I need to avoid the column CreatedDate for Inserting time

Comment: And what's the problem with not showing it in GUI? If you bind to DataGrid, then hide this column.

Comment: Also you could just ignore this property in `OnModelCreating` method of your context: `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Ignore(p => p.CreatedDate);`

Comment: Ok,I did set my Entiy Propety Storegenereator to computed.so now it works,thanks